# The json data can't into Vue router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, json-server

Below is the JSON data that I used for practice API call. But when I try to load the JSON data, I couldn't able to do it.

I don't know why I use `data(){.....`

the `data.json` can't show in web, but in console, `data.json` has be read
like this img:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWDrh.png

---

my `data.json` is:

```
{
  "contents": [
    {
      "content": "456",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
//This is my Vue.js

let List={
      template:
      `<div>
        <p>
          <input type="text" v-model.trim="input">
          <a href="javascript:;" v-on:click="createHandler">Create</a>
        </p>
      <ol>
         <li v-for="(item,index) in contents" :key="item.id">
            {{ item.content }}
        </li>
      </ol>
      </div>`,
      data() {
        return {
          input: '',
          contents:[]
        };
      }
    let router= new VueRouter({
        routes:[
          {
            path:'/',
            name:'list',
            component:List
          },
          {
            path:'/update/:id',
            name:'update',
            component:Edit
          },
          {
            path:'*',
            redirect:'/'
          }
        ]

    })
      new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        router:router,
        mounted() {
          axios.get('http://localhost:3000/contents').then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
            this.contents = res.data;
          })
        }
      })
```

```html
<!-- This is my HTML -->

<div id="app">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4wkqhve/)

first you need to declare a vue component .... because the one you have `let list = {...}` is not a component and the router doesn't recognize it , 
also your vue instance data is not your component data ... you need to pass the array as a prop .... here is how you do it :

```js
var list = Vue.component('list',{
      template:
      `<div>
        <p>
          <input type="text" v-model.trim="input">
          <a href="javascript:;" v-on:click="createHandler">Create</a>
        </p>
      <ol>
         <li v-for="(item,index) in contents" :key="item.id">
            {{ item.content }}
        </li>
      </ol>
      </div>`,
      props : ['contents'],
      data() {
        return {
          input: '',
        }
       }
      })

  let router= new VueRouter({
    routes:[
      {
        path:'/',
        name:'list',
        component:list
      },
      {
        path:'/update/:id',
        name:'update',
        component:Edit
      },
      {
        path:'*',
        redirect:'/'
      }
    ]
  })

   new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    router:router,
    data(){
      return {
        contents : []
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/contents').then((res) => {
       this.contents = res.data
      })
    }
  })
```

```html
<div id="app">
      <router-view :contents = "contents"></router-view>
    </div>
```